# Google OR Tools CP Solver

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver

I am trying to code in C++ to use the new cp SAT solver stated in the link with python demo  above,  however I could not figure out how to get this CP SAT solver in  C++ code syntax, not sure what other type of include is actually  needed for new Cp solver besides "ortools/constraint_solver/constraint_solver.h" 
"ortools/sat/cp_constraints.h"
"ortools/sat/cp_model.pb.h"

```
Below is the workable Cmake which could call other solver GLOP,CBC etc
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(GoogleOR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(Ordir "/usr/local")
include_directories(${Ordir}/lib)
include_directories(${Ordir}/include)
add_definitions(-DUSE_GLOP -DUSE_BOP -DUSE_CBC -DUSE_CLIP)
set(LD_FLAGS "-v -lz -lrt -lpthread")

add_executable(GoogleOR main.cpp)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
link_libraries(/usr/local/lib)
set(Ldir "/usr/local/lib")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      ${Ldir}/libortools.so
                      ${LD_FLAGS})
```

Comment: Please have a look at: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/index.md Please note that we will add a simplified API in the next release (v6.10) due in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Yes, everything is a nupkg file.